# Applying multiple groupings using lodash

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, dictionary, lodash

I would like to group a JSON array by two properties (name and address2) and then reduce it. Here is the current JSON:

```
{
    "clientId": "FOO",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address1": "London",
    "address2": "1 High Street",
    "invoiceNumber": "1234",
    "itemDescription": "Item 1",
    "itemQuantity": 1
},
{
    "clientId": "BAR",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address1": "London",
    "address2": "1 Oxford Street",
    "invoiceNumber": "0987",
    "itemDescription": "Item 2",
    "itemQuantity": 1
},
{
    "clientId": "FOO",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address1": "London",
    "address2": "1 High Street",
    "invoiceNumber": "5678",
    "itemDescription": "Item 3",
    "itemQuantity": 1
}
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
[
    {
        "clientId": "FOO",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address1": "London",
        "address2": "1 High Street",
        "deliveries": [
            {
                "invoiceNumber": "1234",
                "itemQuantity": 1,
                "itemDescription": "Item 1"
            },
            {
                "invoiceNumber": "5678",
                "itemDescription": "Item3",
                "itemQuantity": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clientId": "BAR",
        "name": "JohnDoe",
        "address1": "London",
        "address2": "12 Oxford Street",
        "deliveries": [
            {
                "invoiceNumber": "0987",
                "itemDescription": "Item2",
                "itemQuantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And here is the code that I have so far, which doesn't produce what I would hope it would:

```
        var groups = _.groupBy(rows, function(value) {
            return value.name + '#' + value.address2;
        });

        var data = _.map(groups, function(group) {
            return {
                clientId: group[0].clientId,
                name: group[0].name,
                address1: group[0].address1,
                address2: group[0].address2,
                deliveries: [{
                    invoiceNumber: _.map(group,'invoiceNumber'),
                    itemDescription: _.map(group,'itemDescription'),
                    itemQuantity: _.map(group,'itemQuantity'),
                }]
            }
        });
```

And it produces the following output:

```
[ { clientId: 'FOO',
    name: 'John Doe',
    address1: 'London',
    address2: '1 High Street',
    deliveries: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

I am not sure how to create an array of "deliveries" objects within the lodash _.map function. Please help! :)

Comment: Your code might work just the console.log prints `[object]`. Try to change your log to console.log(client.deliveris) and see if it changes anything

Comment: @Meir - it doesn't work, it creates arrays within deliveries, so invoiceNumber becomes ['1234','5678'],etc. I know I can achieve this by running an additional forEach to iterate over each and built a seperate deliveries object that will be merged with the original array, but surely there must be a better solution.

Comment: If you want to know what is in the [Object]. Do this: `var util = require('util'); console.log(util.inspect(data, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));`

Answer (score 1):

Use one map that picks out the properties you want from a group:

`...
    deliveries: _.map(group, item => _.pick(item, ['invoiceNumber', 'itemDescription', 'itemQuantity' ]))
...`

Comment: I was about to answer this : `deliveries: _.map(group, function(g){ return _.pick(g, ["invoiceNumber", "itemDescription", "itemQuantity"])})`

Answer (score 0):

You weren't far off!

Had a go at making it a little bit more succinct by using ES6 syntax and incorporating `_.pick()` into your code, as suggested by Gruff.

If you really like one-liners, that's possible, too! Lodash makes it easy to chain/nest functions to do this, although you may compromise some readability:

```js
// Data:
const rows = [{
  "clientId": "FOO",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address1": "London",
  "address2": "1 High Street",
  "invoiceNumber": "1234",
  "itemDescription": "Item 1",
  "itemQuantity": 1
},
{
  "clientId": "BAR",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address1": "London",
  "address2": "1 Oxford Street",
  "invoiceNumber": "0987",
  "itemDescription": "Item 2",
  "itemQuantity": 1
},
{
  "clientId": "FOO",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address1": "London",
  "address2": "1 High Street",
  "invoiceNumber": "5678",
  "itemDescription": "Item 3",
  "itemQuantity": 1
}];

// Result:
const groups = _.groupBy(rows, item => item.clientId);
const result = _.map(groups, group => {
  const {clientId, name, address1, address2} = group[0];
  const deliveries = _.map(group, item => _.pick(item, ['invoiceNumber', 'itemDescription', 'itemQuantity']));
  return {clientId, name, address1, address2, deliveries};
});
console.log('multi-liner result: ', result);

// One-line version:
const oneLiner = _.map(_.groupBy(rows, item => item.clientId), group => _.merge(_.pick(group[0], ['clientId', 'name', 'address1', 'address2']), {deliveries: _.map(group, item => _.pick(item, ['invoiceNumber', 'itemDescription', 'itemQuantity']))}));
console.log('one-liner result: ', oneLiner);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Hope that helps! If you'd like more info on the Lodash functions used, here's the official documentation for them:

- [_.groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.1#groupBy)
- [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.1#map)
- [_.pick()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.1#pick)